# How to cite a YouTube Video embedded within a website?

Tags: citations

I would like to cite a youtube video that is inside of another website. The video seems to be taken from youtube, but another website included it. Do I cite the video or the website?

Comment: Cite the original source wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the content of the video itself, you should cite the video. Guidance for citing YouTube videos is available for [APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/youtube-references) and [MLA](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_works_cited_electronic_sources.html) formats.

If you also refer to the commentary on the video from the webpage, you can cite that in addition, similar to how one might cite a book review.