# How do you cite a Youtube video in APA format when the original author of the video is not the channel owner?

Tags: citation-style

I see a Youtube video where the original author is John Doe.  However, the video I found it at was on a channel with a name (let's say ChannelName).  Whether John Doe is the owner of that channel or not I don't know, and Doe doesn't seem to have his own youtube channel.  So...who is the author? Do I cite Doe, or ChannelName?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/172883/68109

Comment: The original author of the video is John Doe, but it wasn't a YT video at that time, right? I.e. ChannelName uploaded a video belonging to John Doe? Otherwise I'm confused how a YT video can have original author JD but be uploaded by someone else?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  John Doe made the video, but someone else put it on Youtube.  For instance, in this particular case it was a professor who did the lecture over video but then gave permission for one of his students to upload it on their channel

Comment: Which style guide do you want to adhere to, depending on where you intend to publish certain guides are preferred over others. Examples: https://liu.cwp.libguides.com/c.php?g=45846&p=291623 https://blogging.com/cite-online-sources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/youtube-references

my previous response apparently was deleted. Here is the link to how to cite the video. Cite original author and there is a space to cite the channel name.